# SMPP error 0xd bind failed

Tags: php, smpp

I use [this](https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp) SMPP library. Here is my code:

```
$transport = new SocketTransport(array($smpphost),$smppport,false,'printDebug'); // hostname/ip (ie. localhost) and port (ie. 2775)
$transport->setRecvTimeout(10000);
$transport->setSendTimeout(10000);
$smpp = new SmppClient($transport,'printDebug');

// Activate debug of server interaction
$smpp->debug = true;        // binary hex-output
$transport->debug = true; // also get TSocket debug

// Open the connection
$transport->open();
$smpp->bindTransmitter($systemid,$password);

  // Prepare message
$message = 'H€llo world';
$encodedMessage = GsmEncoder::utf8_to_gsm0338($message);
$from = new SmppAddress(GsmEncoder::utf8_to_gsm0338('SMPP Tést'),SMPP::TON_ALPHANUMERIC);
$to = new SmppAddress($too,SMPP::TON_INTERNATIONAL,SMPP::NPI_E164);

// Send
$smpp->sendSMS($from,$to,$encodedMessage);

// Close connection
$smpp->close();
```

And error, that I get:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmppException' with message 'Bind Failed' in /home/roman/www/jobeet/php-smpp-master/smppclient.class.php on line 621 SmppException: Bind Failed in /home/roman/www/jobeet/php-smpp-master/smppclient.class.php on line 621 Call Stack: 0.0007 345736 1. {main}() /home/roman/www/jobeet/index.php:0

Could be there errors in my code or it's only SMPP server problem?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your SMSC doesn't support connecting as transmitter+receiver and only expects transceiver connection, which, unfortunately, that particular library doesn't support.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I'll contact SMPP provider and ask that question. And if it will be true is there any library for transceiver connection?

Comment: I really don't know, frankly, I haven't found any opensource SMPP library for PHP that would implement transceiver mode.

Comment: As said in documentation SMPP-server supports both transmitter+receiver and transceiver connections. So the problem should be in anything else.

Comment: Can you catch the exception and see what the error is? (I'm reading the library code and the error status code from the bind command should appear in the exception message.

Comment: In this case that's very little information to go on. I suggest contacting your SMPP provider and asking them about it, surely they can see more about this on their side than you can. It may be something as simple as not having an IP address whitelisted, or using multiple simultaneous connections when only one is allowed, or basically almost any other reason that could prevent connection.